# Blackberry: Mass storage Mode disable

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there any API for disabling the mass storage mode in blackberry?

Comment: Why you need to do that?

Comment: So you want the user to not access the media card even from the phone browser? I dont think you can do this. Try searching of a way to protect the data and not disable the mass storage

Comment: There is an IT policy for that - to be set at the BES server

Comment: NO i want to disable the media card when user connect the phone to the desktop. only i want to disable the use of media card on destop not on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no RIM SDK API available to disable storage mode neither disable usb on the device.
Some restrictions can be made by the BlackBerry Enterprise Server administrator. But it will work only for the devices connected to BES (BlackBerry Enterprise Server).

To protect your data use encryption means provided by RIM SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an API to do that. The user has the option to set mass storage mode to enable, prompt or disable. The user may configure the SDCard to be encrypted. For devices attached to a BES there are ITPolicies that control use of and access to the SDCard and encryption, but I am not familiar with the details.

In general, on the BlackBerry platform, third party programs are not given the ability to over ride the BES admin or user security decisions.

If you can use TinySQL data base there are methods of encrypting the database file and limiting access to the database to module that have been signed by a specified signing authority.

Comment: or Is there means by which i can disable usb port

Comment: Again no API that I know of will do that. How much data do you want to protect? You can put data in the Persistent Store and protect it there.